# Windows-based tethered workflow and automation solution?

Tags: workflow, tethering, product-photography, automation, light-box

I'm setting up a product photography area for a client, where they have a camera (probably a Canon DSLR) tethered to a Windows laptop.

The ideal workflow would be one where the client could shoot, scale, crop and level the photos, attaching product info before uploading to the website (Currently running Joomla! and VirtueMart, may eventually be a proprietary solution more fully integrated with the central warehouse's inventory database.

Because there probably aren't many tethered shooting solutions that integrate directly with VirtueMart (Or if there is, please let me know!), and because I don't want to hand write an interface in Visual C++ or something that's specific to a product database with a high likelihood of future replacement, I'm looking for something that can do the following:

- Photo manipulation -- crop, scale, level (specifically choose white point)
- Photo organization
- Meta data attachment
- Some FTP ability
- Bonus marks for sophisticated batch metadata output (I.e., "save folder metadata to CSV")

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**Adobe Lightroom** does all of the above (apart from the VirtueMart part, sorry!). Tethering (for Canon, Nikon and Leica) and your first four wishlist items are supported right out of the box. The CSV export feature can be added with Timothy Armes' brilliant [LR/Transporter](http://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrtransporter.php) plugin.

Comment: The Free List Exported Photo too is great to setup a bridge between two applications quickly. In less than one hour I wrote a script which parsed its output and uploads exported files and registers them in an online database for my gallery.

Comment: That's helpful. I haven't really looked at Lightroom much, but considering most Windows workflow stuff I've seen has been at least $199 regardless, it might be a possible option. I might try my hand at writing a plugin interfacing it with VirtueMart.

Comment: Yep, I reckoned since you were building a commercial tool, the cost of a Lightroom licence might be within budget. Don't forget there's also the fully-featured trial version if you want to try before you buy.